# spark dataframe filter conditions can't use string

Tags: apache-spark

I used spark 1.3.0

```
df.filter("di4='test'").show()
```

and di4 is my column
the error is

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: AnalysisException: couldn't resolve column reference: 'test'
```

but when i try the

```
df.filter("di5=10").show()
```

its success
anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string based filtering, the long syntax is safer : 
`df.filter(df("di4")==="test")` assuming you actually want to filter on the value "test", and not on some other column named test.